# C# Rearrange text in a string

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have a text with customer information and the information comes in different format and I would like to rearrange the costomer information so all the information looks the same before parsing.

The customer information format 1:

```
ID: 1
Name: A
Last name: B
```

The customer information format 2:

```
ID: 
1
Name: 
A
Last name: 
B
```

Is there any way to so that I rearrange the information so they all looks like the example number 1?

All help is very appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some strings that will be parsed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you *may* just need:

```
text = text.Replace(": \r\n", ": ");
```

That would work for the example you've given, possibly having changed "\r\n" to "\n" depending on the exact format.

Comment: Curse you Jon, beat me to it!  :)

Comment: @Lars: Well if you could give more detail than "This gives error" and a sample in your question, I might be able to. It may be worth starting a new question though, if either my answer or Paul's has answered the original point of *this* question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit more flexible that the simple replacement of ": \r\n", but it can't really ever be perfect

```
 Regex.Replace(input,@"(:\s*)\n([^:]*$)","$1$2",RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

It finds a `:` followed by 0 or more whitespace characters, followed by a newline, followed by a line containing no colons, and removes the newline in this case. The only advantage over Jon's answer is that it will work with empty value, ie:

```
ID: 
1
Name: 
A
Middle Name:
Last name: 
B
```

becomes

```
ID: 1
Name: A
Middle Name:
Last name: B
```

It's OK if thats a requirement, but a lot more complex if not!

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult to write single generic code for any type of format.

However, you could write an interface with a method say Format(...) and create one class for each type of format then instantiate object of class accordingly.